# missing import com.bumptech.glide.signature.StringSignature

Tags: android

Despite added implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0' and annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'

I get this error:
[image: this is my gradle]

Comment: can you add your code ?

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.